# Make a button appear on a userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I want to make a button appear on a userform. I created the userform and added a macro to the button.

This came out when I pressed the button. How do I make this work?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What have you done already?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
NewStudent.Show
```

See the [VBA reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/show-method) for more info

Comment: [And here's why you shouldn't do it that way](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/)